# Converting data from excel file into power point

Tags: c#, python, vb.net, excel, powerpoint

I am wondering if it possible to automate to extract data from multiple exel file , plot a graph and finally present the data in pointpoint using pre-existing template . I tried Python but could go to far with and now some one suggested to use VB. I will really appreciate your help .
Here is my data base looks like

1. Multiple directory containing excel file with following style of name
   dir_1/paint_for_yard1/Blue_light_b2.xls
   dir_1/paint_for_yard1/Red_light_b3.xls
   dir_1/pat_for_yard8/Green_light_b2.xls
   There are multiple file under each directory and contains many data in three columns(pigment-color ,day-run-time, night-run-time)
2. I have a power-point template which needs to be updated based on data from excel file in following format
   Second page(after cover page) should have following in the header
     paint_for_yard1 : Blue_light

   In the body of the page : There is table which gives maximum day_run_time and pigment_color when day_run_time was minimum).
    And then create chart of pigment-color ,day-run-time, night-run-time in the same page.
3. Do the step-2 for each file and add page in the power-point.

As I am not a software expert, I am not sure whether Python or VB or combination will help me or not.
Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Thanks
Anil

Answer (score 1):

Almost any 'grown' programming language can this. So... C# / VB.NET / Python could solve this for you.

I think I would go for a VBA-script inside the PowerPoint template. VBA is made specially for Office and it can communicate with Excel.

Answer (score 0):

I use follow Sub to create a powerpoint presentation from Excel File.

```
Sub Gera_PPT(PFile As String, EFile As String, Plans As Collection)
'officevb.com
'PFile= PowerPoint Template empty powerPoint with Slide Master to presentation
'EFile = Excel File with Charts and Tables
'Plans = A collection with names of sheets to transpose
Dim rg As Range
'objetos usados para o powerpoint
Dim pptA As Object
Dim ppt As Object
Dim sld As Object

Debug.Print "passei 1"


If Not ValidaCaminho(PFile) Then
    MsgBox "PowerPoint file not found!", vbInformation
    Exit Sub
Else
    Set pptA = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
    pptA.Visible = msoCTrue
    'pptA.WindowState = -1
    Set ppt = pptA.Presentations.Open(PFile)
End If

'objetos usados para o Excel
Dim ExA As Excel.Application
Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
Dim sht As Excel.Worksheet


If Not ValidaCaminho(EFile) Then
    MsgBox "Excel file not found!!", vbInformation
    Exit Sub
Else
    Set ExA = New Excel.Application
    'ExA.Visible = True
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(EFile, False)
End If

Debug.Print "passei 2"

'For Each sht In wb.Sheets
For i = 1 To Plans.Count

Set sht = wb.Sheets(Plans(i))

    Select Case Left(sht.Name, 1)

    'Debug.Print "passei 3"
    'case is Table
    Case "T"
           Set sld = ppt.Slides.AddSlide(ppt.Slides.Count + 1, ppt.SlideMaster.CustomLayouts(2))
           sld.Select
           sld.Shapes.Placeholders(2).Select msoCTrue

           Set rg = sht.Range("B4").CurrentRegion
           rg.Copy
           ppt.Windows(1).View.PasteSpecial ppPasteMetafilePicture

    Case "G"
    'Case is 1 Chart

        If sht.ChartObjects.Count = 1 Then

              Set sld = ppt.Slides.AddSlide(ppt.Slides.Count + 1, ppt.SlideMaster.CustomLayouts(2))
              sld.Select
              sld.Shapes.Placeholders(2).Select msoCTrue

              sht.ChartObjects(1).Copy

              ppt.Windows(1).View.PasteSpecial ppPasteMetafilePicture

'              sld.Shapes.Placeholders.Item(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = sht.[A2]
        Else
        'Case is >1 Chart
              Set sld = ppt.Slides.AddSlide(ppt.Slides.Count + 1, ppt.SlideMaster.CustomLayouts(4))
              sld.Select

              sht.Activate

              sld.Shapes.Placeholders(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = sht.Range("A2").Value

              sld.Shapes.Placeholders(2).Select msoCTrue
              sht.ChartObjects(1).Copy
              ppt.Windows(1).View.PasteSpecial ppPasteMetafilePicture

              sld.Shapes.Placeholders(3).Select msoCTrue
              sht.ChartObjects(2).Copy
              ppt.Windows(1).View.PasteSpecial ppPasteMetafilePicture

        End If

    End Select

Next i

'Insert LastSlide
Set sld = ppt.Slides.AddSlide(ppt.Slides.Count + 1, ppt.SlideMaster.CustomLayouts(5))

wb.Close False
ExA.Quit

Strfile = Split(apoio.[PPTFile], "\")

ppt.SaveAs YourFilePath & "\" & Split(Strfile(UBound(Strfile)), ".")(0) & "-" & Format(Date, "ddmmyyyy")

pptA.Quit

MsgBox "Presentation created!", vbInformation

End Sub
```